# itertools.islice triggers UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character error

Tags: python, utf-8

I have the following code to read columns in a csv:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# READS CSV, RETURNS LIST OF COLUMN DATA, FROM ROW rowStart TO rowFinish
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def csvColumnAsList(csvFileName, column, rowStart, rowFinish):
    column_list = [] # defines it as a list
    with codecs.open(csvFileName, 'r', 'utf-8') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in itertools.islice(spamreader, rowStart, rowFinish+1):
            column_list.append(row[column].decode('utf8'))
    return column_list
```

but this triggers an error:

```
File "algo-8.py", line 51, in csvColumnAsList
    for row in itertools.islice(spamreader, rowStart, rowFinish+1): UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in
position 215: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can someone help me.
I tried a few things with encode, decode, but can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Examples section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) of the module's documentation. There it states (below the 6th code sample):

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode [...] [But] you can write functions or classes that handle the encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.

At the page's end there is a ready-to-use implementation.